# Stuck in tty1 login

Tags: login, tty

In tty1 login after giving the username and password it shows the screen again asking for login and can't get rid of it. I tried using Ctrl+alt+f7 and others but it doesn't work

Comment: Login in in the tty1 is not a common scenario for the typical user. Please provide detail on your use case. Is this a server? Is this through a remote connection? Ubuntu version?

Comment: Well I tried to install steam and it maybe broke something. I am using 20.04.3

Comment: Add information that describes the context, clarifies what you really want, etc. to the question: use "edit". Comments are not necessarily read, and my disappear. Your question, however, is for reference for future users that may have the problem.